# "Switch Applications" does not work in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, application-switcher

Since upgrading to 12.10, sometimes "Switch Applications" does not work.

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works as pressing only <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.
And it does not work even if I change the shortcut key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or any other.

Comment: try meta+w that might work

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can try installing `CompizConfig Settings Manager` by using a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

or by using the software center:

[image: Install via the software center]

and select `Application Switcher` or `Static Application Switcher` from `Window Management` group.

Comment: How to install the CompizConfig Settings Manager?

Comment: sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager or go to ubuntu software center and search for compiz manager

Comment: Since some recent update of 12.10, the `Static Application Switcher` is now in a separate package called `compiz-plugins`