# change alt-tab to ctrl-tab on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout, apple, application-switcher, remapping

I have an apple [USB keybord](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard) for my Ubuntu 12.04. I remapped command left key to control for convenience. And now I switch between apps with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and between tabs within one app with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. It's normal but not comfortable and painless.

It would be ideally to remap shortcuts as opposite: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> - switching between apps, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> - between tabs. Can I do it? xmodmap?

UPDATE: here is a screenshot of settings which I apply, **restarted** but it hasn't changed:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You can change your Keyboard Settings from System >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts.

[image]

Under Navigation, you should see "Switch Application". You can click it and set the new short cut as you want. Hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried, set exactly as in the your pic, but nothing changed. What can I do wrong?

Comment: I think you have to restart to get the effect. Some examples can be found here . http://askubuntu.com/questions/206820/switch-applications-does-not-work-in-12-10

Comment: restart didn't help. I uploaded a screenshot to the question. So I set as in the screenshot, then restart and it didn't help

Comment: For crazyheads like me running Debian/Ubuntu on Mac: It solves the problem with remapping Alt to Command too!

Answer (score 5):

For certain Keyboard shortcuts you need to also edit these in dconf-tools. At least on 12.04.

Install dconf-tools and start dconf-editor.

Navigate to org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings and change the "switch-windows" key.

Answer (score 4):

For Unity Tweak Tool:

**Step 1:** Option Selector

[image: Step 1: Option Selector]

**Step 2:** Change. I use "Alt+c" is more comfortable for me.

[image: Step 2: Change. I use "Alt+c" is more comfortable for me.]